# Update dataframe row given condition on duplicate

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like

```
    id      occurence    status
0   1       1            validated
1   2       1            validated
2   3       1            validated
3   1       10
```

The association [id, occurrence] is unique meaning I will only have 1 combination [1, 1] or [1, 10].
The row with the occurrence 10 will always be added on the dataframe after the one with the occurrence 1.

What I want to do every time I see new rows with occurrence 10 is checking that another row with the same id and occurrence 1 exists, then extract the status from the row [id, 1] and update the status of the row [id, 10] accordingly.

For now I can extract duplicated like this

```
df[df['id'].duplicated(keep=False)]
```

which return a dataframe with all duplicates but I do not know how to do the part where I select the value of the status for the first occurrence...

I also tried something like this:

`df.groupby('id').transform(lambda x: x.update({'status': 'validated'})` with a static value at first but it gives me a dataframe filled with None...

Any idea about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can align the DataFrames with a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
m1 = df['occurence'].eq(10)
m2 = df['occurence'].eq(1)

df.loc[m1, 'status'] = (df[['id', 'occurence']]
       .merge(df[m2].assign(occurence=10),
              on=['id', 'occurence'], how='left')
       .loc[m1, 'status']
      )
```

Output:

```
   id  occurence     status
0   1          1  validated
1   2          1  validated
2   3          1  validated
3   1         10  validated
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.assign(status = df['status'].where(df['occurence'].eq(1)).groupby(df['id']).transform('first'))
```

Output:

```
   id  occurence     status
0   1          1  validated
1   2          1  validated
2   3          1  validated
3   1         10  validated
```